# Byte primitive in Java

Tags: java, byte

I have been working on a project with images and I read on internet that working in `byte` for images solves alot of problems and improve efficiency. I tried to google it but didn't find any definition for it. So I came here to ask

- What is byte in Java? What is it use?

Comment: It's the very first Google hit for me: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html.

Comment: I wonder if people ever read the specifications of the languages they are programming in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

> byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`byte` is one of the primitive types of java. Is an abstraction of a byte (8 bit integer **with** sign).